# Monitor a Java standalone application with Prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

Not able to see any examples of monitoring a Java standalone application with Prometheus. The questions are:

- Can we use Prometheus for Java standalone applications?
- If yes, then what do we need to do?

Comment: share your code. what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have currently three choices:

1. Expose a Prometheus End-Point: this is done by exposing a HTTP end-point that can be scraped; either [writing by hand the content](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) or using Prometheus [Java Client Library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java)
2. Use a sidecar application: in your case, it would be the [JMX exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)
3. If your application is short lived: generate a prom file (i.e. [expostion format] into a file) and drop it to an existing node exporter or use a push gateway (not the first choice)